# subbundles & slice charts

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $F\hookrightarrow E \overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} M$, $F'\hookrightarrow E' \overset{\pi'}{\longrightarrow} M'$ two smooth fiber bundles.

If $F'\subset F$, $M'\subset M$, $E'\subset E$ are embedded submanifolds and $\pi'=\pi|_{E'}$.
Then is the following chart condition true?

$\forall p \in M'$, $\exists U\ni p$ open in $M$ and a chart $\phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\longrightarrow U\times F$ of $E$ that $\phi|_{\pi'^{-1}(U\cap M')}:\pi'^{-1}(U\cap M')\longrightarrow (U\cap M') \times F'$ is a chart of $E'$

Ps: I have the later for definition of subbundle, but I think it's equivalent to the first.

Comment: $\pi^{-1}(U\cap M')$ is diffeomorphic to $(U\cap M')\times F$. Think of the example $F=S^1$ and $F'=[0,1]$: then, the pullback along $\pi'$ will still be "spherical" while while the product with $F'$ will be "linear".

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write $\pi'^{-1}(U\cap M')=\pi^{-1}(U\cap M')\cap E'$, not $\pi^{-1}(U\cap M')$. I edited the question. I don't understand your example, $F'$ is not a submanifold of $F$.  My question is similar to the proposition of this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333590/slice-charts-of-subbundles